# The code doesn't compile in VS2010, but when I pass the cursor over j in A.h, I can see the tooltip showing const int j = 10. How come?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I believe the code doesn't compile, because I'm using the `extern const int j` to initialize `i` in `class A`. But according to the Standard, why is this wrong ?

File A.h

```
extern const int j;

class A
{
    static const int i = j;     //  error C2057:expected constant expression
};
```

File A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

const int j = 10;

int main()
{
    A a;
}
```

Comment: constant expression is different from a constant variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j` is a constant variable, not a compile-time constant.

The compiler can't know the value of `j` in the translation unit that compiles `class A`. For example, the following would work:

```
static const int j = 10;

class A
{
    static const int i = j;
};
```

Note that in this case `j` will not be global, but a copy will exist for each TU. The snippet is here just to prove a point.